# Why dont we use Given's method to reduce a symmetric matrix to diagonal form rather than tridiagonal form, and why is tridiagonal form desirable?

Tags: matrices, symmetric-matrices, tridiagonal-matrices

I've been searching for a while trying to understand why we use Givens method (and householders method) to reduce a symmetric matrix to tri-diagonal form instead of using these methods to reduce a matrix to diagonal form, similar to the QR decomposition. Since surely diagonal form is more desirable, and on this note, why would it be desirable to reduce a matrix to tri-diagonal form. Thank you for any help anyone can give towards helping me understand this small point.

Comment: A main reason of interest is that the theory of orthogonal polynomials uses tridiagonal matrices. See the excellent presentation :(http://www.math.hkbu.edu.hk/ICM/LecturesAndSeminars/08OctMaterials/1/Slide2.pdf) aroud slide 18

Comment: Here are some of the reasons : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanczos_algorithm#Application_to_the_eigenproblem